# Как не сохранять в модель поле отмеченое как required и unique при редактировании?

Tags: yii2

есть модель User

вот правило

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['username', 'required'],
            //['username', 'match', 'pattern' => '#^(p{L}|p{Zs}|p{N}|,|-|_ | |)+$#i'],
            ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => self::className(), 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
            ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

            ['email', 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => self::className(), 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],
            ['email', 'string', 'max' => 255],

            ['status', 'integer'],
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => array_keys(self::getStatusesArray())],
        ];
    }
```

есть необходимость разрешить пользователю изменения только ника вопрос, а как в данном случае отключить проверку email потому, что модель не валидируется из за то, что или емаил не уникальный или его надо заполнить?

Comment: Необходимо сделать сценарии и расписать для каждого из них отдельные правила валидации.
Или же, в реквесте прописывать какой-то дополнительный параметр и отлавливать его в блоке-условии валидации.

Comment: @withoutname а есть гдето годная информация по сценариям, а не та что предлагает оф документация

Comment: я вообще здесь смотрел здесь, https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/structure-models/#validation-rules .
Но в конечном итоге не использовал на продакшене, обошли сценарии с помощью beforeAction в контрлере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения проблемы можно использовать сценарии.

Добавляем сценарий внутри модели следующим образом:

```
const SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'updateInfo';
```

Также необходимо объявить в функции `scenarios()` атрибуты валидации:

```
public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_UPDATE => ['username', //... ],
        //...
    ];
}
```

Перед использованием модели объявляем сценарий:

```
$model->scenario = User::SCENARIO_UPDATE;
```

В правилах указываем, что валидация имейла не используется когда сценарий `SCENARIO_UPDATE`:

```
[['email'], 'required', 'when' => function(){
       return !$this->scenario == self::SCENARIO_UPDATE;
}],
```

Comment: @LAV, вместо правки ответа (не являющегося общим) лучше оставить комментарий со своими замечаниями.